# Search all disk images for a file name?

Tags: command-line, grep, search, disk-image

When backing up many SD card images onto a large HDD, I am not sure whether one SD card is already included or not.

I would like to search all the images for a file name saved on that card, e.g. `20190722_021059.jpg`, with one command.

I could use `grep`, and somehow figure out how to only scan the file table instead of the entire image (i.e. first 20 MB of the image), but is there any other way?

Should I mount every image and search the mounted file system then? If so, how do I mount every image with one command?

Comment: When you say "many SD card images", do you mean tens, hundreds, thousands, or more? To achieve what you need "in one command", you'll have to write a script that will repeat the necessary actions for every card image, and then your "one command" will be just to run that script. For tens of images, your script might indeed mount all the images and then use `find`; for thousands, it might be a better idea to save a list of contents of each card once, and then search a directory of contents list files whenever needed. Using a database might allow even faster searching.

Comment: @telcoM Below 100 images. Roughly around 50, but not exactly sure.